# How do I avoid duplicating rows in this scheme?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I try to join tables storing billed qty and purchase order qty. The problem is that in the PO the material can appear twice. So when I join them material B appears four times with qty 7-7, 7-11, 11-7 and 11-11 although only the 7-7 and 11-11 are right.
What would be the solution for this?

(I can only use the query, can't change the table structure)

```
CREATE TABLE vbrp (
    Billing_doc INT,
    Bill_doc_line INT,
    Material VARCHAR(255),
    Billed_Qty DECIMAL(10, 2),
    Po_Num INT
);

INSERT INTO vbrp (Billing_doc, Bill_doc_line, Material, Billed_Qty, Po_Num)
VALUES
(111, 15, 'A', 12, 2811),
(111, 16, 'B', 30, 2811),
(111, 17, 'C', 2, 2811),
(111, 18, 'D', 21, 2812),
(111, 19, 'E', 22, 2811),
(111, 20, 'F', 10, 2811),
(121, 10, 'HH', 7, 2811),
(121, 11, 'HH', 6, 2877),
(121, 12, 'R', 10, 2877),
(122, 7, 'A', 8, 2814),
(122, 8, 'B', 7, 2814),
(122, 9, 'B', 11, 2814),
(122, 10, 'C', 23, 2814),
(122, 11, 'D', 2, 2814),
(122, 12, 'E', 7, 2814),
(124, 2, 'T', 10, 77),
(124, 3, 'U', 1, 12);

CREATE TABLE ekpo (
    Po_Num INT,
    Material VARCHAR(255),
    PO_qty DECIMAL(10, 2),
    PO_line INT
);

INSERT INTO ekpo (Po_Num, Material, PO_qty, PO_line)
VALUES
(2812, 'D', 21, 10),
(2877, 'HH', 6, 7),
(2877, 'R', 10, 8),
(2814, 'A', 16, 21),
(2814, 'B', 7, 22),
(2814, 'B', 11, 23),
(2814, 'C', 35, 24),
(2814, 'D', 2, 25),
(2814, 'E', 7, 26),
(77, 'T', 17, 1),
(12, 'U', 1, 2),
(2811, 'A', 12, 1),
(2811, 'B', 30, 2),
(2811, 'C', 2, 3),
(2811, 'E', 22, 4),
(2811, 'F', 10, 5),
(2811, 'HH', 7, 6);

SELECT vbrp.Billing_doc, vbrp.Material, vbrp.Billed_Qty, ekpo.PO_qty
FROM vbrp
JOIN ekpo ON vbrp.Po_Num = ekpo.Po_Num AND vbrp.Material = ekpo.Material
WHERE vbrp.Billing_doc = 122;
```

Comment: it is important to inform what SGDB you are using, either in your question or add a corresponding tag (mysql, postgresql, etc)

Comment: As a non-expert in sales automation I quite like the question, however it would benefit from removing irrelevant data and leaving only the lines related to document #122, and probably only to materials A,B, and C. The rest of the data is only distracting from the question. I wonder if there are common tricks to fix a broken data model, or whether it is not possible.

Comment: Depending on details of how Bill_doc_line and PO_line are generated which may or may not be reliable then https://dbfiddle.uk/hYm7sWw7 - otherwise these tables are not fit for the purpose you are trying to use them for

Comment: Though the best thing to do would probably be to abandon trying to pair the rows up and just aggregate both sides https://dbfiddle.uk/DnqhdbW6

Comment: You might want to add to the join condition the `Billed_Qty` and `PO_qty` columns, though without more information about your system, this is nothing more than a speculation, probably worst than Martin Smith's about `Bill_doc_line` and `PO_line`.

Comment: The solution is to go back in time and add a po_line column to your billing table

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, because `Material` and `Po_Num` in table `vbrp` is not a unique identifier for a row in table `ekpo` that you join against. If you add `Po_Line` to `vbrp` then you can join on that also and you will have your unique identificator. But because you can't change the schema, it's not possible.